# Plotting a graph - Different line styles for different edges

Tags: matlab

I have a graph of nodes and edges that I am plotting against `(x, y, z)` coordinates for each node.

I would like to use a dotted line for the "inner" edges, and a straight line for the "outer" edges.

`LineStyle` may help me, but I think that will make all of my edges dotted lines. I would like to specify which edges are dotted.

Here is the code I am using to plot the graph: (`G` is a graph)

```matlab
plot(G, 'XData', A(1,:), 'YData', A(2,:), 'ZData', A(3,:))
```

Any help is much appreciated!

I have a function to create the graph, it gives this output:

```matlab
G =
graph with properties:
    Edges: [11×1 table]
    Nodes: [6×0 table]
```

And a coordinate system similar to this:

```matlab
A =
     0     1     0    -1     0     0
     0     1     3     2     1     2
     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

Using the plot function above, this provides this output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can help you

Comment: Post ```XData, A, YData and ZData```. Also add your current plot graph.

Comment: Done, couldn't embed the image as I don't have enough reputation

Comment: I guess, you have to manually select the "inner" and "outer" edges, e.g. encoded by an array of logicals, and then simply plot both sets using different line styles. I doubt, that there is some pre-defined function to automatically detect "inner" and "outer" edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok you didn't really put enough effort in making your question easy to answer for everybody but I was curious about a method and it seem to work so I'll post it anyway.

The classic trick for these cases where a sub-group of points/lines have to be plotted differently than the whole group is to:

1. Plot the whole group
2. Plot the sub-group on top with different line properties

In your case, it means you have to find the points and edges which are part of the boundary. I'll explain one method below. Be aware that this method will only work for **convex** boundaries (see the difference with a *concave* set where the method wouldn't work: [concave vs. convex hull](http://ubicomp.algoritmi.uminho.pt/local/concavehull.html) ).

First I need to get to the state of your question, so let's consider:

```
%% Initial data
A =[ 0  1  0 -1  0  0
     0  1  3  2  1  2
     1  1  1  1  1  1 ];
G = graph ;
G = addedge(G,[1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 4 4],[2 3 4 5 6 3 5 6 4 5 6]) ;
plot(G, 'XData', A(1,:), 'YData', A(2,:) , 'LineStyle','--')
grid on ; hold on
np = size(A,2) ;            % Number of points/nodes
```

This will produce a figure exactly like yours, with only one `linestyle`, which was set to dashed lines for the full graph. The exercise is now to plot a contour with a solid line.

To find the contour (at least in 2D cases like yours), the method used is:

1. find one point of the contour (initial point), the lowest `x`
   possible.
2. calculate the angle between unit vector `ux=[1,0,0]` and
   all the other vectors (formed by the initial point and all the other
   points of the matrix).
3. Assign the next point of the contour (it is the one which vector has
   the minimum angle) . You now have a current vector `vec` (between
   point 1 and 2), and a current point `pt2`.
4. Calculate the angle between `vec` and all the other vectors (formed
   by the current point `pt2` and all the other points of the matrix)
   the next point of the contour is the one which vector has the
   minimum angle.
5. Repeat (3) and (4) until the next point of the contour is the
   starting point.

---

Translated in code:

```
%% find a point on the edge
% (I chose to start with the lowest point on Y axis)
[~,idxNext] = min(A(2,:)) ;

%% initialise counters
isOnEdge = false(np,1) ;    % this will hold a logical register of contour points
idxEdge = idxNext ;         % this will hold the points of the contour, in order

%% setup start conditions
isOnEdge(idxNext) = true ;  % initial point
p = A(:,idxNext) ;          % initial point
v = [1;0;0] ;               % initial vector (start with unit vector oriented Ox)

%% search for contour
isRunning = true ;
iter = 0 ;
while isRunning
    iter = iter + 1 ;               % make sure we're not stuck in infinite loop
    angs = find_angles(v,p,A) ;     % find angles between initial vector and all other points
    angs(idxNext) = Inf ;           % Exclude current point
    if numel(idxEdge) > 1           % Exclude last point (if not at first iteration)
        angs(idxEdge(end-1)) = Inf ;      
    end
    [~,idxNext] = min(angs) ;       % find the index of the minimum angle 

    if isOnEdge(idxNext)
        % we've completed the close profile, bail out
        isRunning = false ;
    else
        % move on to next point/vector
        idxEdge = [idxEdge idxNext] ; %#ok<AGROW>
        isOnEdge(idxNext) = true ;
        p = A(:,idxNext) ;
        v = A(:,idxNext) - A(:,idxEdge(end-1)) ;
    end

    if iter > np
        break                       % make sure we're not stuck in infinite loop
    end
end

%% present results
if isRunning
    fprintf('Could''t find a closed profile\n')
else
    fprintf('Found points defining a closed profile:\n')
    disp(idxEdge)
end

%% Plot on top of graph
% create a matrix conataining only the contour points, close the contour by
% replicating the first point in last position
C = [A(:,idxEdge) , A(:,idxEdge(1))] ;
% plot
plot3( C(1,:) , C(2,:) , C(3,:) ,'b', 'LineWidth',2)
view(2)
```

Which will yield:

[image]

---

In the script above I am using the function `find_angles.m`. The code for it:

```
function angs = find_angles(Uin,p,M)
% find angle between Uin vector and the vectors formed between p and 
% all the points in M
np = size(M,2) ;
angs = zeros(np,1) ;
for iv=1:np
    vec = M(:,iv) - p ;
    c = cross(Uin,vec) ;
    d = dot(Uin,vec) ;
    angs(iv) = rad2deg( atan2( norm(c) , d ) ) * sign( c(3) ) ;

    % take care of an edge case
    if c(3)==0 && d==-1 ; angs(iv) = 180 ; end

    % give [0 360] degree results
    if angs(iv) < 0 ; angs(iv) = 180 + (180+angs(iv) ) ; end
end
```